# How to do proper recursion in Pyparsing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm currently parsing a custom programming language, and, when creating the "expression" rule for parsing, I'm struggling to find a way that's not painfully slow with recursion.
My problem is that a function call can be in an expression, and an expression can be in a function call (parameters). So what I end up with is a terrible system based on `Forward()`, that takes seconds on `func1(var1+1) + 1` and minutes on `func1(func1(var1+1)+1) + 1`, which is for sure not acceptable.
Here's my current bad approach:

```py
    expression = Forward()
    functionCall = Forward()
    value = literal ^ identifier ^ Group(functionCall)
    expression << Group(infixNotation(value, [
        (memberOP, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
        ...
    ]))
    arguments = ZeroOrMore(delimitedList(expression))

    ...

    functionCall << identifier + Literal("(").suppress() + Group(arguments) + Literal(")").suppress()
```

Comment: Did you enable PyParsing's packrat optimisation?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Wow, this was instantaneous ! Now I feel dumbfounded, but I guess that's how you learn. Feel free to add an answer I would validate.

Comment: More performance tips here: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki/Performance-Tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyParsing can remember previous parse results and re-use them using the Packrat optimisation. This is provides a performance benefit for recursive grammars or generally if an element may apply in different contexts.

Packrat must be manually enabled, since it might conflict with parsers that have side-effects (e.g. a parse action that modifies global state).

```
import pyparsing
pyparsing.ParserElement.enablePackrat()
```